# How to inherit a class attribute that is a dict and make it unique?

Tags: python

This works as I expected;

```
class Foo(object):
    name = ''

class Bar1(Foo):
    pass

class Bar2(Foo):
    pass

Bar1.name == Bar2.name # returns True
Bar1.name = 'Bar1'
Bar1.name == Bar2.name # returns False, which is what I want.
```

This doesn't work the same, but I want it to;

```
class Foo(object):
    fields = {'name':''}

class Bar1(Foo):
    pass

class Bar2(Foo):
    pass

Bar1.fields['name'] == Bar2.fields['name'] # returns True
Bar1.fields['name'] = 'Bar1'
Bar1.fields['name'] == Bar2.fields['name'] # returns True, which isn't what I want.
```

It seems the subclasses are still pointing at the same dict object specified in the main class, but I want them to have unique dicts. How can I do this without writing `fields = {'name':''}` in each of the subclasses?

PS- I definitely do want to use class level attributes, not instance attributes, as all of the instances I create will use this 'shared' dict.

Comment: Just a clarification about that PS: you want every _subclass_ to have new "fields" dictionary, that will be the same for all its _instances_? That's kinda strange. Are you sure Foo shouldn't be a _metaclass_, with Bar1 and Bar2 its _instances_, not subclasses? I mean, you obviously use Foo as a template for creating Bar1 and Bar2, you're _not_ sharing objects between them.

Comment: In case you want that, here is a oneliner: `class Foo(type): __new__ = lambda metaclass, name, bases, namespace: super().__new__(metaclass, name, bases, dict(namespace, fields = {'name': ''}))` :-D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is using a meta-class (I've assumed Python 2.x syntax):

```
class FieldsMeta(type):

    def __new__(mcs, name, bases, dict):
        """This controls the creation of each new class."""
        dict.update(fields={'name': ''})
        return type.__new__(mcs, name, bases, dict)


class Parent(object):
    __metaclass__ = FieldsMeta


class Child(Parent):
    pass
```

In use:

```
>>> Parent.fields
{'name': ''}
>>> Child.fields
{'name': ''}
>>> Child.fields is Parent.fields
False
>>> Child.fields['name'] = 'Child'
>>> Child.fields
{'name': 'Child'}
>>> Parent.fields
{'name': ''}
```

See e.g. the [data-model documentation for `__new__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__):

> [`__new__`] is also commonly overridden in custom metaclasses in order
>   to customize class creation.

and the section on [customizing class creation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-class-creation).

Answer (score 0):

You can create fields setter, which will copy dict before assign new value

```
class Foo(object):
    fields = {'name':''}

    def set_field(self, field, value):
        self.fields = dict(self.fields)
        self.fields[field] = value

class Bar1(Foo):
    pass

class Bar2(Foo):
    pass

Bar1.fields['name'] == Bar2.fields['name'] # returns True
# Bar1.fields['name'] = 'Bar1'
Bar1.set_field(Bar1, 'name', 'Bar1')
print(Bar1.fields['name'] == Bar2.fields['name']) # returns False
```